# Connecting WiiU Minecraft and an Android

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, wii-u, minecraft-legacy-console

My kids want to both play Minecraft with their cousin in another state at the same time. The problem: 2 kids, 1 Wii U. Can I somehow connect a tablet to the WiiU platform so both of my kids can play with their cousin?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you get your information.  I play the Wii U with both of my children, the only thing you need are additional pro controllers.  The standard wiimotes WILL NOT WORK.  Then you go into settings in Minecraft and select multiplayer split screen.  The Pro Controllers run $60, they are the same layout as the Wii U game pad minus the touchscreen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way, in fact i'm quite sure that the only way for them to play together is on these four consoles:the Xbox360, the Xbox1, the Ps3, and the Ps4. I believe that that is it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot connect Pocket Edition (Android) Minecraft with the Wii U version.  Each version of minecraft is separate from the rest.

The only option would be to have two Wii U consoles and connect the two over Nintendo Network (the Internet).

---

<strike>You can, however, play splitscreen on the Wii U version.  You will need an HDTV, the Wii U Gamepad, and a Wii U Pro Controller.  Other peripherals such as a Wiimote with an attached Nunchuck or Classic Controller will not work.</strike>

First, start up Minecraft and load a world.  Then, on the Wii U Gamepad, touch the icon in the bottom right corner of the screen. It looks like a Gamepad with an arrow pointing to the TV.

Once you touch that icon, the Gamepad's screen will show a grass block on a dirt background.  Then, pick up the Pro Controller and press <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Start</kbd> (or <kbd>+</kbd>).  Minecraft will then show a Mii selector.  Select the Mii to play with, then press <kbd>A</kbd> and you will be playing in splitscreen.  The Wii U version supports up to 4 players in splitscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Gamepad and a Pro Controller in split-screen if you have a HDMI connection to your TV and a HD tv (so 720p or higher).

Comment: I'm  not really seeing how this answers the questions at hand.

Comment: Considering the question is about two people in different states, telling how to play splitscreen really doesn't help.